# Any package for editing i18next locale files?

Tags: package

I am looking for a package that allows editing i18next locale files in emacs.

Comment: What does an i18next locale file look like? Is it just JSON?

Comment: Could be JSON as well as other formats, but the same schema has to be maintained across all the files